# Reading a json file from s3 bucket

Tags: file, http, flutter, dart

"I have a File on amazon s3 bucket with the url,the file is in json format,i want to read the file and store it in list in flutter"

```
HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse("mobile_app_air_ports.json"))
.then((HttpClientRequest request)=> request.close())
.then((HttpClientResponse response){
Future<List<String>> 
test=response.transform(Utf8Decoder()).toList();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your data model, then parse your JSON:

```
import 'dart:convert';


class YourDataModel {
  final String yourData;

  Post({this.yourData});

  YourDataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return YourDataModel(
      yourData: json['yourData'],
    );
  }
}
```

```
Future<List<String>> fetchData() async {
  final response =
      await http.get('mobile_app_air_ports');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON
    return (json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>)
        .map<YourDataModel>((item) => YourDataModel.fromMap(item))
        .toList();

  } else {
    // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}
```